# I need to create a column with the number of times the same value is kept in the table. SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a rank column grouping by the same id and sorting by date using sql.
I wanted to check how many times the blue red and yellow values are repeated in order.

My data in SQL Server

| date | id | color | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202006 | 4 | blue | 1 |
| 202007 | 4 | blue | 2 |
| 202008 | 4 | blue | 3 |
| 202009 | 4 | red | 4 |
| 202010 | 4 | blue | 5 |
| 202011 | 4 | blue | 6 |
| 202012 | 4 | yellow | 7 |
| 202101 | 4 | red | 8 |
| 202102 | 4 | red | 9 |
| 202103 | 4 | blue | 10 |
| 202104 | 4 | blue | 11 |
| 202105 | 4 | blue | 12 |
| 202006 | 8 | blue | 1 |
| 202007 | 8 | yellow | 2 |
| 202008 | 8 | yellow | 3 |
| 202009 | 8 | yellow | 4 |
| 202010 | 8 | yellow | 5 |
| 202011 | 8 | yellow | 6 |
| 202012 | 8 | red | 7 |
| 202101 | 8 | red | 8 |
| 202102 | 8 | blue | 9 |
| 202103 | 8 | blue | 10 |
| 202104 | 8 | blue | 11 |
| 202105 | 8 | blue | 12 |
| 202012 | 9 | yellow | 1 |
| 202101 | 9 | yellow | 2 |
| 202102 | 9 | yellow | 3 |
| 202103 | 9 | blue | 4 |
| 202104 | 9 | red | 5 |
| 202105 | 9 | red | 6 |

I want to create a column with the number of times the same color is repeated in the table

| date | id | color | rank | repetitions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202006 | 4 | blue | 1 | 1 |
| 202007 | 4 | blue | 2 | 2 |
| 202008 | 4 | blue | 3 | 3 |
| 202009 | 4 | red | 4 | 1 |
| 202010 | 4 | blue | 5 | 1 |
| 202011 | 4 | blue | 6 | 2 |
| 202012 | 4 | yellow | 7 | 1 |
| 202101 | 4 | red | 8 | 1 |
| 202102 | 4 | red | 9 | 2 |
| 202103 | 4 | blue | 10 | 1 |
| 202104 | 4 | blue | 11 | 2 |
| 202105 | 4 | blue | 12 | 3 |
| 202006 | 8 | blue | 1 | 1 |
| 202007 | 8 | yellow | 2 | 1 |
| 202008 | 8 | yellow | 3 | 2 |
| 202009 | 8 | yellow | 4 | 3 |
| 202010 | 8 | yellow | 5 | 4 |
| 202011 | 8 | yellow | 6 | 5 |
| 202012 | 8 | red | 7 | 1 |
| 202101 | 8 | red | 8 | 2 |
| 202102 | 8 | blue | 9 | 1 |
| 202103 | 8 | blue | 10 | 2 |
| 202104 | 8 | blue | 11 | 3 |
| 202105 | 8 | blue | 12 | 4 |
| 202012 | 9 | yellow | 1 | 1 |
| 202101 | 9 | yellow | 2 | 2 |
| 202102 | 9 | yellow | 3 | 3 |
| 202103 | 9 | blue | 4 | 1 |
| 202104 | 9 | red | 5 | 1 |
| 202105 | 9 | red | 6 | 2 |

Comment: You can't add a column like this to a table (unless you use a trigger which is a _very bad idea_). You can create a view though. How many rows are in this table?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a `rank` column, i assumed it is in the order of `[date]`

```
select *,
       repetitions = row_number() over(partition by id, [color], grp 
                                           order by [rank])
from
(
    select  *,
            grp = [rank] - dense_rank() over (partition by id, [color] order by [rank])
    from    yourtable
) d
order by id, [rank]
```

EDIT : missed out the `id` in the `dense_rank()` part

Comment: Very good!
But when the color changes the repetition is restarted.
Start counting the sequence again.
In the code you passed the sequence continues.
Every time the color changes the repetition starts from 1 again.
I only need to count consecutive repetitions.

Comment: Updated the query. Missed out `id` in the `partition by`

Answer (score -1):

I think your question should be. How to group column data in a sql query and order by descending order?

You should do queries like.

```
select count(columnName1), columnName2, columnName3, ... , columnNameN
from tableName
where condition
GROUP BY color
order by count(columnName1)
```

I think this should help you, not definatly but i guest you get point.

Comment: You should avoid queries like this with sql. it's better with linq or entity framework when you have more control and make less mistake when typing.

Comment: That SQL is not valid and won't give a rank anyway. I also disagree with the LINQ comment. Are you recommending LINQ because of autocomplete? Most SQL client tools have autocomplete as well.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, i didn't say it was valid. i didn't want to post an answer. I wish i could put a comment. But it's says that i have less than 50 rep, so put a comment.

Comment: The goal was for him to anderstand want the schema look a bit.

Comment: i need to know how many months the same color is repeating on the same id

Comment: This data you're showing - is it from a table or from a view?